# Finding the size of an array of pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to find the size of an array of pointers. The array is declared as such:

```
Student *students[ROSTER_MAX];
```

where `ROSTER_MAX` is a static const int that == 1024 and `Student` is an object that contains an int and two strings. I'm trying to find the size of `students` (e.g. the number of elements in the array). So far I have tried:

```
sizeof(students)/sizeof(*(students[0]));
```

and

```
sizeof(students)/sizeof(students[0]);
```

If anyone could help me understand why the previous two (especially the first one) isn't working and provide an alternative, it would be appreciated!

update:
I'm trying to find the number of non-null elements in the array. The constructor for the array class (called `Roster`) is:

```
Roster::Roster(){
  this -> numStudents = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < ROSTER_MAX; i++){
    this -> students[i] = NULL; 
  }
}
```

so I can see how the above lines of code would lead to 1024. But I'm trying to find the number of initialized elements.

Comment: `Size of a pointer` (usually size of uint) multiplied by `ROSTER_MAX`

Comment: Can you expand this to a [mcve]? It's important, because the techniques you're trying to use only work in certain circumstances. They also only tell you the number of elements in the array, not which are actually used. Under those circumstances, which are the array was declared in that scope and has not decayed to a pointer, the second should work as would `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)`

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking. The number of elements in the array is `ROSTER_MAX`. These three expressions will yield `ROSTER_MAX`: `sizeof(students)/sizeof(students[0])`, `sizeof(students)/sizeof(*students)`, `std::size(students)`. You already know that there are `ROSTER_MAX` elements so why are you trying to calculate it? Perhaps I have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Why aren’t you using a `std::vector<Student>`?

Comment: If you want to write C instead of C++, the number of initialised students is probably `numStudents` but you really, really should be using `std::vector<Student>` instead.

Comment: Sorry guys, I figured it out! I used a loop to count the number of uninitialized elements. Seems obvious now of course :)

Comment: Other option is `Student *students[ROSTER_MAX] = { NULL };` to initialize all pointers `NULL`. So long as you fill no more than `ROSTER_MAX - 1` you can iterate `size_t count; while (students) count++;` - which is know as using a *Sentinel NULL*.